# How can I get 100% CPU saturation with simple WCF app?

Tags: c#, wcf, testing

I am trying to write simple client-server application that can use 100% of CPU using WCF.

Program is sending 10000 times request and is receiving string like in example below. I am sending f9b6af85-8826-49c8-9524-39511f1a241a and receiving  "Hello f9b6af85-8826-49c8-9524-39511f1a241a" for 10000 times and I measure time.  I tried to increase number of clients from 2 to 4, but CPU is used on 30%. Service is very simple and it is self hosted in console application. Client is web form application. I need advice: what should I do to get 100% CPU usage? Should i send more request, increase number of clients, send bigger message or do something else that I am missing?

Service:

```
public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
    public string Hello(string name)
    {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

Host:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HelloWcf.HelloService)))
        {
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Host started @ " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            label1.Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            var start = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            HelloServiceReference.HelloServiceClient client;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                label2.Text = string.Empty;

                client = new HelloServiceReference.HelloServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHelloService");

                label2.Text = client.Hello(label1.Text);
                client.Close();
            }

            var end = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

            var totalTime = end - start;

            label3.Text = string.Format("Total time of execution {0}", totalTime.ToString(@"mm\:ss\.ffff"));

            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
```

Comment: Most likely your CPU isn't pegged because I/O is the bottleneck.  To make I/O *not* be the bottleneck, you'd have to do something more CPU-intensive when handling the requests.

Comment: do more iterations? run multiple instances at once?

Comment: "what should I do to get 100% CPU usage" - why? A developer's goal is to  *reduce* CPU usage.

Comment: This application is for validation purpose.
I tried with more iterations 100000 but there was little increase with CPU usage.  

@adv12 what can I do for exp? Do some mathematical operations?  I also turn off TCP offloading.

Comment: If its for validation i think then 30% is probably all you can get. If you insist on 100% then its more like cpu benchmark tool.

Comment: Use [Prime 95](http://www.mersenne.org/download/)

Comment: @TimFreese Unfortunately I need to use WCF app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to queue some threads, something like this:

```
for (int cont = 0; cont < 100; i++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((a) =>
    {
        while (true) 
        { 
        }
    }));
}
```

Put it on your requests, it will raise a lot your memory usage.

Comment: You mean inside my for loop on client, or in service before I send response?

Comment: If you want to stress the memory of your server, you can put in your wcf method before send the response

Comment: Ok, i have now 100% of CPU usage when I send request, but what this is doing exaclty when I  send reques??

public string Hello(string name)
    {
for (int cont = 0; cont < 100; count++)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((a) =>
    {
        while (true) 
        { 
        }
    }));
}
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

Comment: and there is also a problem when response is send CPU stays on 100%.

Comment: ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem puts a task in a queue to be executed and wait for it finishes, but with the while(true) line, it will never finish, so o raise the cpu usage as you wanted.

Comment: cpu at 100% will crash your system, only use to reach your goal and then stop.

Comment: If my answer helped you, don't forget to mark as useful, or the best answer if resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example program that I used to answer [WCF performance, latency and scalability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710220/wcf-performance-latency-and-scalability/7745600#7745600). The full command line code is included.

The threading code uses an older pattern because its from 2011. However it can still fully consume any CPU.